# Filter the numbers of records returned from two collections

Tags: c#, linq

I'm not sure if I'm going about this correctly but I'm trying to filter the collection. I'm working the concept of an item and kit. A kit is made up of one or more items. If the user does not have access to any of the items in the kit, then he does not have access to the kit.

I have a collection of all of the products and another collection of all of skus the user has access to.

In the example below, the user would not have access to the kit since he does not have access to one if the items.

I was thinking about creating a new list with only the products he has access to. Please see below, Thoughts? Also, i could be doing this for 10K products.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var allProducts = GetAllProducts();
        var allowedSkus = GetAllowedSkus();

        var allowedProducts = GetAllowedProducts(allProducts, allowedSkus);

        Assert.IsTrue(allowedProducts.Count() == 1);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Product> GetAllowedProducts(IEnumerable<Product> allProducts, IEnumerable<string> allowedSkus)
    {
        var products = new List<Product>();
        var skusinAllProducts = allProducts.Select(x => x.Sku);

        foreach (var product in allProducts)
        {
            if (product.ItemType.Equals("Item", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                products.Add(product);
            }
            else
            {
                //Need help here, not sure if I'm going about this correctly...
                var skusInKit = product.Components.Select(x => x.Sku);

                bool contains = true;

                foreach (var sku in skusInKit)                    {                       

                    if (!skusinAllProducts.Contains(sku))
                    {
                        contains = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (contains)
                {
                    products.Add(product);
                }
            }
        }

        return products;
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> GetAllowedSkus()
    {
        var skus = new string[] { "item-001", "item-003" };
        return skus;
    }

    private IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        var list = new List<Product>();

        var item001 = new Product
        {
            ItemType = "Item",
            Sku = "item-001"
        };

        var kit001 = new Product
        {
            ItemType = "Kit",
            Sku = "kit-001",
            Components = new List<Component>
            {
                new Component
                {
                    Sku = "item-002",
                    Quantity = 1
                },

                new Component
                {
                    Sku = "item-003",
                    Quantity = 1
                }
            }
        };

        list.Add(item001);
        list.Add(kit001);

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you familiar with lambda expressions..? you can do this with that just quickly glancing at your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you have some mistake in the line:

```
var skusinAllProducts = allProducts.Select(x => x.Sku);
```

And it should be just the `allowedSkus`. Otherwise it doesn't make sense, but correct me if I'm wrong and I'm missing some of your logic.

Then the Lambda expression that you need in your case is:

```
var products = allProducts.Where(p => 
                            p.ItemType.Equals("Item", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                            (p.ItemType.Equals("Item", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false &&
                            allowedSkus.Contains(p.Components.Sku)))
                            .ToList();
```

This will replace your entire `foreach`.